# Change "for" attribute when specific input is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I got multiple lightboxes but only one link

```
    <label class="btn" for="modal-2">more...</label>
```

I want the "for" attribute to change to "modal-3" when the input with the id "id3" is selected, and to "modal-4" when "id4" is selected etc.
when i change the "for" attribute manually, it works but i dont want to change my code all the time just to open another modal :D

```
                   $(document).ready(function() {

                      $("#id3").on("change", function() {
                        if (document.getElementById("id3").checked) {
                          $('.btn').attr('for', 'modal-4');
                        }
                      });
                    });
```

I got this already and this won't work. In my html file there's another script tag for the header of my website. Does this affect my other script?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? Can you attach a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't get an error message. It just don't work.

Comment: But in your labels you do not have any ID.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle. You can clearly see that its not working... https://jsfiddle.net/xn5k5edk/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use a class for your lightboxes such as "lightbox".

Then you can write in one function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.lightbox').on("change", function() {
         if ($(this):is('checked')) {
                     id = $(this).attr('id');
                     num = id.substr(2); // for instance id3 will get you 3
                     $('.btn').attr('for', 'modal-'+num);
                     }
                  });
                });
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question but I thought he meant he needed a way to make it for every modal item, and only managed to do it when manually inputting the id number.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xn5k5edk/1/ The problem is that all the time, the same lightbox shows up. But i want to open another lightbox, when for example the 3rd picture is selected.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "when the input with the id "id3" is selected, and to "modal-4" when "id4" is selected", what do you mean by selected? the code you provided will execute when the value of the HTML element with id = "id3" changes. This is not what you wanted.

Comment: id3 and id4 are id's for inputs. and i want to change the "for" attribute depending on which input is selected

Comment: Inputs cannot be selected...I dont know what you are talking about.